# Cannot bind TCP/TLS listener socket to addr XX.XX.XX.XX:3478

Tags: linux, centos, c, turnkey

After installing and configring turnserver on a CentOS-7.X server, I meet the following poblem.

```bsh
$ ./turnserver
... 
...
0: Cannot bind TCP/TLS listener socket to addr 39.39.39.39:3478              
0: Trying to bind TCP/TLS listener socket to addr 39.39.39.39:3478, again... 
bind: Cannot assign requested address                                         
0: Trying to bind fd 257 to <39.39.39.39:3478>: errno=99                     
Cannot bind local socket to addr: Cannot assign requested address             
0: Cannot bind TCP/TLS listener socket to addr 39.39.39.39:3478              
0: Trying to bind TCP/TLS listener socket to addr 39.39.39.39:3478, again... 
bind: Cannot assign requested address                                         
0: Trying to bind fd 258 to <39.39.39.39:3478>: errno=99                     
Cannot bind local socket to addr: Cannot assign requested address             
0: Cannot bind UDP/DTLS listener socket to addr 39.39.39.39:3478             
0: Trying to bind UDP/DTLS listener socket to addr 39.39.39.39:3478, again...
```

This is my `turnserver.conf` file.

```
listening-ip=39.39.39.39        
listening-port=3478              
tls-listening-port=5349          
relay-ip=39.39.39.39            
external-ip=39.39.39.39         
relay-threads=50                 
lt-cred-mech                     
userdb=/etc/turnuserdb.conf      
# no-stdout-log                  
log-file=/var/tmp/turnserver.log 
pidfile="/var/run/turnserver.pid"
```

I try to open some port, which doesn't work.

```bsh
$ firewall-cmd --list-ports
3478/tcp 3478/udp
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the output of `ip a s` and `netstat -tulpn`.

Comment: `errno` 99 is for `EADDRNOTAVAIL` is that address available on you computer?